# unable to add service reference in wcf application

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration

the problem : when adding service reference -> chosing the address http://localhost:8000 -> pressing GO

> There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8000'.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8000/'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8000/ that could accept 
>   the message.
>   This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively 
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:8000
>   If the service is defined in the current solution,
>   try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

The service contract :

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://www.thatindigogirl/2011/12")]
public interface IHelloIndigo
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();
}
```

The service :

```
public class HelloIndigo : IHelloIndigo
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The host's `app.config` :

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="HelloIndigo">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000" />
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="HelloIndigoService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                 name="basicHttp" contract="Host.IHelloIndigo" />
            <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding"  name="mex"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />                
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

- This solution was rebuilt from an vs2008 to vs2010 I changed the framework to 4.0 in both projects client and host .
- The configurations were made by the wcf configuration wizard.

Any idea why the client project can't locate the host end point to retrieve the metadata ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you open that address in a browser, do you get the service page?

Comment: Your service is definitely not running, based on the exception you're seeing.

Comment: yes, i run the host and go to localhost:8000 
and the service is there.

Comment: both projects are in the same soultion 
if i run the host project i can't choose the Add service reference 
option on the client project 
maybe i can't locate a service in this way if they are in same soulotion , i wasn't able to locate the service with the Discover option of the Service reference wizard.

Comment: what is the HelloIndigoService in the first endpoint?

Comment: thats the service im exposing at 
http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigoService
maybe the way i'm exposing the metadata is wrong ?

Comment: Your host needs to be running for you to be able to do discovery on it.

Comment: true , but they are in the same soulotion i can't make changes to the
Client project when the Host project is runing .

Comment: Not if you run it from the IDE, correct. What type of host is it - stand-alone EXE? If so, you can run it from the command-line while proxying it.

Comment: finally that did the trick
i didn't want to run it because i once came across a way that it could generate a proxy from the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably that the service is not running.

It could also be that port 8000 is blocked.

Edit:

Based on your comment that the discover does not work within the same solution: This means that something is wrong with the project type.

Thry to create a new WCF project, add the services you need, then copy over your existing code.

Comment: iv'e attempted to change the port but still no dice.

Comment: well the service is not runing 
my question then how could i run the service and add a service end point at the same time if they are in the same soulotion

is the only way in this case to add a reference to the host assembly
but also the problem arrsies that i can't add the service reference at run time .

btw Discover also doesn't work ( it does not locate the service in the soulotion).

Answer (score 0):

Try with http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigoService

Comment: no... i'm trying to expose the metadata from the mex endpoint

Comment: Is it working? If yes, please mark it as answer. So, someone can use this as a reference.

Comment: it's working but not for the reason you stated 
there was another answer here that i think someone removed , that helped me out. 

btw : http://...../HelloIndigoService is the service itself 
what i need is to expose it's metadata through the http://.../mex address , what you suggested is only for reaching the service itself . i was a attempting to create a proxy .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while revising an existing web odata service and then attempting to establish a new service reference to the revised service in a Silverlight project. By temporarily commenting out the authentication and authorization sections in the web.config file I was able to connect to and download the metadata from the data service to my Silverlight project. Rick Moulton

Answer (score -3):

I was trying to do the same thing you were, adding a service reference only to run into a connection error because the current service wasn't running.

In order to pull this trick off, you need to open two Visual Studio Instances and use one to first Open the "Add Service Reference" Menu. With the menu open, in your other Visual Studio, debug your application so that your service is running.

While the service is running enter the address in the "Add Service Reference" menu and it WILL find your URL listening service. Only then can you select the interface or class you wish to reference.

After that's done you can stop the debugging and the changes will take effect. You may get a warning that your project was modified outside the editor just click OK and you'll be good.